# lost connection error when launching the application on the emulator IOS when using flutter_downloader

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, mobile, download

lost connection error when launching the application on the emulator when using flutter_downloader

when I made an application project on flutter it went well in the emulator but when I tried to add flutter_downloader it couldn't run on the IOS emulator, just after the build was successful the application force closed. I have tried for IOS configuration
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader

[image: Main Page]

Info.Plist

[image: PlistFile]

[image: Swift]

Method Download

[image: Do Download]

[image: PortCall]

Answer (score 0):

which uses

```
flutter channel stable
```

update flutter, then I reinstalled flutter (reinstall the plugin).

If an error occurs in pubspec.yml, downgrade or upgrade the library.

```
flutter clean
```

it works, the application can run even though the function is not yet functional